# no such column: portfolio_project.description

Tags: python, django

Error de la columna portfolio_project.description

Error:
**OperationalError at /admin/portfolio/project/
no such column: portfolio_project.description**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes publicar tu modelo? quizás tienes un typo en el nombre de la propiedad (column)

Comment: Has probado migrar de nuevo la base de datos?